# Fourier Transform in real life

Tags: fourier

what is the frequency spectrum mean in real life ? , if we said x(t) , we mean that each time we have an output which is represented by x(t) , also it can represent decaying ,growing of an object , it can represent the power of an object accroding to it's time . but how can i understand the X(f) , if we say that X(f) represent a power according to it's frequency , it's not make sense , because frequency is not an abstract thing that can we deal in real life , like time , we can not "feel" it , to give better understand for my question , let's say that x(f) is zero at f=5 , how this reflect in the time domaine ? , I  know that my question is a kind of 'philosphy' rather than 'electrical' :)

Comment: We do sense frequencies directly, namely in accoustics. You may notice that when you *look* at a sampled sound signal (e.g. music) you cannot easily make out which notes are played simultaneously and their respective power, though you may be able to hear it. Doing an fft of the same signal will make visible the composition of notes/frequencies; and, because computers usually deal with magnitudes of values only, transformation to the frequency domain makes frequency-depending numerical operations possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your title indicated you were interested in the use of FT's in real-life.  One application where I have made use of FTs is the decoding of touch-tone signals, like those generated on a telephone keypad. Each "touch-tone" is a superposition of two tones, selected from a set of four columns (1209 Hz, 1336 Hz, 1477 Hz, 1633 Hz) and four rows (697 Hz, 770 Hz, 852 Hz, 941 Hz).  (Wait, you say your telephone only has 3 columns of buttons?  There is actually a provision for four more buttons along the right side labelled A, B, C and D, which was used in the military.)

This picture shows what the combination of 941 Hz and 1336 Hz looks like on an oscilloscope:

[image]

One can see there is a regular pattern here, but no way to separate out the two tones.

If however you run this signal into a spectrum analyzer, which performs a FFT (Fast Fourier Transform), you get this:

[image]

The two peaks correspond to the frequencies 950 Hz and 1330 Hz.  Not exactly the ones listed earlier, but this probably represents slightly-off oscillators in the telephone keypad.  The frequencies chosen for the eight tones were designed so the two frequencies in each pair would be far enough apart to allow for some leeway.

Back before microcontrollers were invented (and even after, when they were not fast enough to handle this sort of thing), decoding of touch-tones was done in hardware using a set of analog filters, one for each of the eight frequencies.  Here is a Western Electric touch-tone decoder, circa 1965.  The analog filter circuitry is contained on the plug-in cards to the right (with the orange markings).

[image]

This circuitry was later reduced to an IC, first the LM567 (one chip per column) and then the HT9170 which used highly accurate switched capacitor filters to decode all 16 combinations of tones.

With microcontrollers, and particularly DSPs (Digital Signal Processors), things have become much easier.  Initially DSPs were separate chips, and had to be combined with a microprocessor to form a complete system.  Now they can be combined into one chip.

I used a Microchip dsPIC33FJ256GP710 (which, as the name implies contains a DSP in addition to a general purpose microcontroller based on the PIC24, and costs around $6). I also used a free DTMF decoder library (most of it written in assembly language) that performs the FFT, and generates two outputs corresponding to the peaks in the earlier picture.  So I was able to decode DTMF tones coming into the microcontroller's ADC without adding any addition hardware.  Meanwhile the microcontroller was free to perform all of the other functions of the device I was building.

Answer (score 3):

Frequency is a very real thing that we deal with in real life if we are working with radio signals. A spectrum display such as the posted pictures is commonly used to monitor signal(s) being received and watch for drift, or interference from nearby signals or jamming, and even to estimate visually what kind of modulation the signal uses. The display can also be used to monitor an entire band to see where the action is.

Answer (score 1):

$$x(f) = 0 $$

For f = 5 means that your signal `x` does not have any frequency components at 5 Hz. Similarly, if you have a signal:

$$x(t) = sin(120\pi t)$$

Then a transform that into the frequency domain would show a single impulse at f = 60 and all other frequencies will be zero. Therefore, the FT allows you to see the frequency components of a signal. Here, for example, is the real-time [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) of some input signal:

[image]

So whatever that input signal was, this plot shows it had components in the frequencies surrounding those peaks. All that clutter at the bottom is noise received from the environment and internal circuitry.

[image]

As another example, whatever this input signal was it must of had high relative magnitudes of the 1280Hz frequency.